# Bool search: must_not is not useful

Tags: search, kibana, devtools

**I use bool to search,it like this:**

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match": {
                "message": {
                    "query": "disconnect"
                }
            }
        },
        "must": {
            "match": {
                "message": {
                    "query": "server"
                }
            }
        },
        "must_not": {
            "match": {
                "message": {
                    "query": "pomelo_list"
                }
            }
        },
        "must_not": {
            "match": {
                "message": {
                    "query": "socket"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter": {
      "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2018-03-15T07:21:56.950Z" }} 
    }
    }
}
```

}

**the result like this:**
[image]

**We can see that which doc contain "pomelo_list" is in the result,**
**Why must_not is not useful?**
**How can i do to make the search result right?**

Answer (score 0):

First, must must_not need to be array.

Second you need to use query_string

```
{"query": {
"bool": {
    "must": [{
        "match": {
            "message": {
                "query": "disconnect"
            }
        }
    },        
        "match": {
            "message": {
                "query": "server"
            }
        }
    ],
    "must_not": [{"query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["message"],
        "query" : "*pomelo_list*"
    }
    },       
        "match": {
            "message": {
                "query": "socket"
            }
        }
    ],
    "filter": {
  "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2018-03-15T07:21:56.950Z" }} 
}
}
```

}